# F# Pattern Matching Nested Discriminated Unions

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

I've a nested discriminated union representing a deck of playing cards:

```
type Symbol =
| Seven
| Eight
| Nine
| Ten
| Jack
| Queen
| King
| Ace

type Card =
| Heart of Symbol
| Diamond of Symbol
| Spade of Symbol
| Club of Symbol
```

Now I want to write a function returning the value of a given card which in my case is independent of the cards suit:

```
let GetValue (card : Card) =
  match card with
  | Heart(Seven) -> 0
  | Diamond(Seven) -> 0
  | Spade(Seven) -> 0
  | Club(Seven) -> 0
  ...
```

This is obviously tedious to write. Is there a way to do something like this

```
let GetValue (card : Card) =
  match card with
  | _(Seven) | _(Eight) | _(Nine) -> 0
  | _(Ten) -> 10
 ...
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You won't be able to bypass constructor matching in that fashion, but you can remove some tedium by creating a function to pull the symbol out of a card:

```fsharp
let symbol card =
  match card with
  | Heart(s) -> s
  | Diamond(s) -> s
  | Spade(s) -> s
  | Club(s) -> s

let GetValue (card : Card) =
  match symbol card with
  | Seven | Eight | Nine -> 0
  | Ten -> 10
  ...
```

Answer (score 11):

You're modeling your data incorrectly. Since the total deck is the full Cartesian product of suits and ranks, it doesn't make sense to "wrap" ranks in suits. The two should be independent, equally important attributes of a card:

```
type Rank =
  | Seven
  | Eight
  | Nine
  | Ten
  | Jack
  | Queen
  | King
  | Ace

type Suit =
  | Heart
  | Diamond
  | Spade
  | Club

type Card = { suit: Suit; rank: Rank }

let getValue (card:Card) = 
   match card.rank with
   | Seven | Eight | Nine -> 0
   | Ten -> 10
   ...
```

Comment: @dlkmp - This is the right answer. Chad Gilbert's answer works, but as long as you have an incorrect data model, you're going to keep encountering more problems like this. Get your data model right and the rest of the code will tend to flow much more naturally.

Comment: I agree that the data model in my example is not very clever but the underlying question focused on pattern matching nested discriminated unions. This cannot be solved as I wished and Chad Gilbert's answer addressed to that, so I'll keep this as the right answer. I'll change my data model, nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way:

```
let set789 = [Seven; Eight; Nine] |> Set.ofList
let cardValue x =
    match x with
    | y when Set.contains y set789 -> 0
    | Ten   ->  1
    | Jack  ->  2
    | Queen ->  3
    | King  ->  4
    | Ace   ->  5
    | _     -> -1

let GetValue (card : Card) =
  match card with
  | Club(x) | Spade(x) | Diamond(x) | Heart(x) -> cardValue x
```

Comment: `y when y = Ten` is super redundant and equivalent to just `Ten`.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin - Thanks, I fixed it.